# How do I insert and retrieve geography data in asp.net mvc connected with Entity Framework and using dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dapper

I'm new using geography data types and using dapper and I've been searching on the internet for a while but most of the answers aren't for geography type or are outdated. I'm working on a project using google's API to track dynamically but for now it's ok if it just shows various locations i introduce, Any help is appreciated.

Here's the model of my geography table, it's not complete but for now I just need to insert and retrieve data, also my latitude and longitude attributes are null so that I can introduce dynamically any data through a device

```
[Table("GEOGRAPHY")]
public partial class GEOGRAPHY
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public GEOGRAPHY()
    {
        DEV_GEO = new HashSet<DEV_GEO>();
        RECORDs = new HashSet<RECORD>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID_ROUTE { get; set; }

    public DbGeography LAT { get; set; }
    public DbGeography LONG { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(2)]
    public string ISO { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string COUNTRY { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string NICENAME { get; set; }

    [StringLength(3)]
    public string ISO3 { get; set; }

    public short? NUMCODE { get; set; }
    public int PHONECODE { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<DEV_GEO> DEV_GEO { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<RECORD> RECORDs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the specific question ?

Comment: EF or dapper? pick one :)

Comment: @Shyju sorry if i wasn't specific enough, my question is how do i use dapper to insert and retrieve data from database

Comment: @MihailShishkov dapper

Comment: @frederickramirez Did you check the dapper documentation ?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @DavideMauri i created the database in sql server

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you are using SQL Server, than you can take advantage of specific SQL Server feature support. I wrote an article, along with sample code, on that:

https://medium.com/dapper-net/sql-server-specific-features-2773d894a6ae

The key points are

1. SQL Server Spatial data types are not yet available in .NET Core
2. Using the "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" assembly can turn into a
   versioning nightmare, double check your app.config to make sure you
   are referencing the latest version